# How to add sliding transition animation to IndexedStack?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with IndexedStack and I would like to add a sliding transition animation when the page is changed with the Bottom Navigation Bar (NOT fade animation).
This is an abstract of my code:

```dart
class _LoggedHandleState extends State<LoggedHandle> {
  
  int _selectedPage = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        
        title: Text("title"),
        
        
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white60,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Hello',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              label: 'Account',
            ),
          ]),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedPage,
        children: [HelloView(), HomeView(), UserView()],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

PS: I need to use IndexedStack in order to mantain the state, so I can't use PageBuilder

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, `IndexedStack` is just a `Stack` of elements that will show the current tab on top. To achieve what you want I'd suggest to do something similar, yet different, like this:

```dart
class LoggedHandle extends StatefulWidget {
  final _pages = <Widget>[HelloView(), HomeView(), UserView()];

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LoggedHandleState();
}

class _LoggedHandleState extends State<LoggedHandle> {
  var _selectedPage = 0;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('title'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white60,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        onTap: (i) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedPage = i;
          });
        },
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Hello',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: widget._pages[_selectedPage],
    );
  }
}
```

Then, for the animation, [there's a Widget for that (AnimatedSwitcher)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html). By exploiting that, along with an `AnimatedWidget` of your choice (or a custom one), you'll be good to go.

```dart
body: AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 650),
  transitionBuilder: (child, animation) =>
      ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child),
  child: widget._pages[_selectedPage],
),
```

Comment: This way will conserve the state as IndexedStack does?

Comment: What `state` do you need to preserve between rebuilds? I can see you've just got a `selectedPage` variable in your widget. That's ephimeral state, and indeed it will be used and preserved to handle the transitions.

Comment: I deleted the parts not related to the question, but I Need to preserve the state between the indexedstack

Comment: I can't see how state and this choice of Widgets are connected, they shouldn't be.

Comment: I use IndexedStack instead of PageBuilder because IndexedStack preserves the State while navigating with BottomNavigationBar

Comment: What state is preserved? I don't get it.

Comment: I deleted the part related to the state because Is not needed for this question.

Comment: I solved by using PageView and AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin